# VS2005 + cant select windows service as project type

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

i was just about to finish up my project and install it as a windows service.  I have the installer, etc. - everything i need.  When i went to choose Application Type, Windows service does not appear as an option.

Here is the kicker.  When I dev in VB.NET, i have that option.  The project mentioned above is in c#.

Also, if i try to add a new project, i cannot select windows service as a project type.  From within the project i can add a windows service and an installer class.

Any ideas or am i just forgetting something stupid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an installer class in your project, then you need a Setup project which will incorporate the output of the project's build.

See here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984464(VS.71).aspx for a great walkthrough.

Comment: Wow, thank you - thats lame tho! I can create the projecet in VB.NET and just select Windows Service as output, thats sux i have to create an installer project just because its c#.  Oh well. Thank you for the article/anser :-0)

Answer (score 1):

In my copy of Visual Studio 2005, when I create a new project it's not listed directly under the C# project type, but under C#->Windows

Here there should be a project type called "Windows Service" which sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: I can select that as a project type for a new project, but in the application tab of that project, i still cannot select Windows Service as an output type.

Answer (score 1):

I posted here:

What i ended up doing was creating a sep class file that created an instance of the winservice - compiled it as a windows service then used installutil to install the service - works like a champ and i didnt have to create an installer project :-)